# Selenium WebDriver wait (visibilityOfElement) with c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriverwait

I was using selenium java before. There is such a method in java ;

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOf(final WebElement element)
```

I cannot find it in c#. There is such a method in C# ;

public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsVisible(By locator)

In this case, I have to give a locater to the method I created every time. However, I want a method where I can directly give the element. How could this be possible. ?

Comment: > I cannot find it in c#. There is such a method in C# ;

Should one of the C# be an other language

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is, how do you use WebDriverWait to wait for an element to become visible. If that's true, you simply need to call the Until method on the WebDriverWait object and pass ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible as the argument.

See code below, using a 30 second wait.

Doing it all with one line of code:

```
IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(id)));
```

Split up into several lines for clarity:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(id)));
```

Comment: public static void sendKeysFunction(WebElement element, String value) { waitUntilVisible(element); element.sendKeys(value); Look at this method please; I can pass just the element in the method. I use POM and i put all the objets in the same class. they are allready located in the page class. I want the call the elements which are located

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ElementToBeClickable`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable_1.htm) method.
It accepts a `IWebElement element` as a parameter.
I agree with you that this is not exactly what element visibility means, however element visibility and element clickability `ExpectedConditions` methods are internally implemented similarly.

Comment: You are right  ElementToBeClickable accept IWebElement element as a parameter. But 
it doesn't working for some elements of my framework

Comment: I see.. But why not to use `ElementIsVisible` method accepting `By` as a parameter? It is very useful. Unfortunately there is no `ExpectedConditions` for element visibility accepting a `WebElement` parameter in `C#`.

Comment: public static void sendKeysFunction(WebElement element, String value) {
        waitUntilVisible(element);
        element.sendKeys(value);        Look at this method please;  I can pass just the element in the method. I use POM and i put all the objets in the same class. they are allready located in the page class. I want the call the elements which are located.

Comment: I see. But this will not be possible with `C#`. Also, it's better to pass a locator and to locate the element directly before you are going to access it rather than passing a `WebElement` object. This may cause `StaleElement` problems.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of *Java* based line of code:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOf(final WebElement element)
```

in *C#* would be [*ElementIsVisible()*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) method which os defined as follows:

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsVisible(
    By locator
)
```

An example would be:

```
IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("ElementID")));
```